# select a column and frequency of column value in spark scala or spark java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table like below.

```
select * from employee;

eid     salary  location
1003    1007    wyd     
1006    1009    mah     
1008    1100    ind     
1009    1100    mah     
1010    1100    mah
```

I need to find the frequency of similar salary(how many entries in the table with the same salary) and location along with the eid

In hive, i have written a query like below and it works.

```
hive> select eid, count (*) over (partition by salary) as levelCount, count(*) over (partition by location) as areacount from employee;


1003 1 1    
1006 1 3   
1008 3 1   
1009 3 3   
1010 3 3
```

How to write a similar one in spark by operating on dataframe.

Comment: @vindev: Yes, this is what i was doing before. But i wanted to do it without using hive query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple `window` function as below

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

def commonWindowSpec(colName: String) = Window.partitionBy(colName)

df.select(col("eid"), count("salary").over(commonWindowSpec("salary")).as("levelCount"), count("location").over(commonWindowSpec("location")).as("areacount")).show(false)
```

It is almost the same as you have used the query in your hive sql.

You should get the following output

```
+----+----------+---------+
|eid |levelCount|areacount|
+----+----------+---------+
|1008|3         |1        |
|1009|3         |3        |
|1010|3         |3        |
|1003|1         |1        |
|1006|1         |3        |
+----+----------+---------+
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for, Thanks @ramesh :)

Answer (score 0):

**I have the same problem, and I solved it doing this code below:**

```
public Dataset<Row> frequencyValuesAnalysisWOLim(Dataset<Row> dataSet, String attribute) {
    return dataSet.groupBy(col(attribute)).agg(size(collect_list(attribute))
            .as("count")).select(col(attribute), col("count")).orderBy(col("count").desc());
}
```